# save form data for next visit

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jsp

I have a page with form in my web (using jsp).
My question is: There is option to go to another page and return to this one without losing the form data. the javaScrip Command-

```
history.back();
```

is not good because before I return to the form I pass in several pages (move then one).
There is a way to save this data or I need to create a semi program with javaScript/jsp/java for it?

Comment: Do you want to save the data client side ?- if so can use `localstorage` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Storage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This](http://garlicjs.org/) is what you need. If you want to try on your own @Duke's solution works well.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the JavaScript functionality localStorage/sessionStorage is something you should use. When you go to another page, the form data should be serialized and stored in either the localStorage or sessionStorage.

Simple localStorage example:

```
localStorage.lastname = "Smith";
```